# How to print "\0025cf" in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm rendering some HTML that uses the pseduo `before` element to render bullet points by setting the `content` value

```
.lst-kix_mnfdzhrfoeyd-0>li:before {
    content: "\0025cf";
}
```

But when I'm printing this in PHP the string is truncated to `5cf` which means the bullet points won't render.

I've tested this with a simple PHP script and can confirm it happens. Any suggestions? As you can see from the var_dump the preceding character is present as the character count is 4.

```
<?php
    $s = "\0025cf";
    print $s;
    // 5cf

    var_dump($s);
    // string(4) "5cf"
```

Update:

I wrongly put single quotes in the PHP example, but was infact using double-quotes. Having changed the assignment of the string the necessary HTML to use a string literal there is no need to escape the characters. As pointed out in the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: how the var_dump is truncating the string this way is real mistery for me. Even the backslash is not escaped it should output the numbers. I have tried your code and the print, aswell the var_Dump are giving `\0025cf`

Comment: You've highlighted my error, using double-quotes was meaning the string needed escaping, using single quotes like the example I wrongly posted was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to literally output `\0025cf` then it's as easy as `echo "\\0025cf";`

If you want to output the character represented by that code, it's not as easy. If you're outputting to HTML context, then try `echo "&#x25cf;";`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to do `echo '\0025cf';`, single quotes so we don't have to escape the string?

Comment: @user555 that's the fix, I need to use a string literal (single quotes) rather than a string (double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $s = "\\0025cf";
     echo $s;
```